# Insert new rows into existing table on view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-table

This is my table in the view (cshtml) :

```
  <table id="tblketquatk" class="thongke2socuoi">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>Số</th>
                <th>Ngày về gần nhất</th>
                <th>Số lần xuất hiện</th>
                <th>Số ngày chưa về</th>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

In the controller :

```
    [HttpPost]//Run action method on form submission
    public ActionResult LastTwoSubmit(string cityID, string numbers, int days, bool onlySpecial)
    {
        // get the result from sql server based on the parameters 
        // now i want to append the result to the table tblketquatk
        return View();
    }
```

Now I want to append the result to the table tblketquatk, is there anyway to do this without using Javascript?

I've done this before using JQuery, which will use Ajax to append the result into the exisiting table without reloading the page.

Link to [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/307p7L3j/) for a better look.

What I want is how to insert the newly returned dataset into the table, and the parameters on the form remain unchanged/reset.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What model are you returning to the view? You need pass a collection, then loop through that collection to create each row.

Comment: The only way you can stay on the same page and append data from the server is to use ajax, so no, its not possible without javascript. Otherwise you need to post the values with a normal submit and return a whole new page that renders a new table

Comment: @StephenMuecke I get it, can you tell me how to render the new page with the new result and the parameters stay unchanged?

Comment: By _parameters stay unchanged_ do you mean, render a table with the new item(s) you get in the controller as well as the existing items that were showing previously before you submitted?

Comment: @StephenMuecke The above table contains the parameter I need to execute the StoredProcedure, after executing, the result data will be inserted into the below table, when the page is re-rendered with the new data, I need the parameters to stay unchanged, so the user will know where does the data come from. Please take a look at this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/307p7L3j/1/

Comment: You need to use a model and bind to that model (both ways) in order to 'retain' the values when you return the view.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I made it, using a Partial View and a model that contain both parameters and result dataset. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need models to bind to so that model can be returned to the view

```
public class SearchViewModel
{
  public int Days { get; set; }
  ....
}

public class MainViewModel
{
  public SearchViewModel Search { get; set; }
  // Add a property for the collection of items you are rendering in the table
}
```

View

```
@model MainViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Search.Days)
  ....
  <input type="submit" ... />
}
// add loop to create table rows
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult LastTwoSubmit(MainViewModel model)
{
  // use the values of model.Search to query the database and add to the model collection
  return View(model);
}
```

because you form properties are now bound to a model and your returning that model, the values will be retained when you return the view.

Comment: I made it using a partialview and a model contains both parameters and result dataset. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Lots of ways to skin a cat. Good you worked it out yourself :)